# Instance_eval doesn't have access to class in module

Tags: ruby, binding, module, scope, instance-eval

I've came across an issue with `instance_eval` and module inclusion.

Please take a look at the following code:

```
module B
  class C
    def initialize
      puts 'This is C'
    end
  end

  def hello
    puts 'hello'
  end
end

class A
  include B

  def initialize(&block)
    hello
    C.new
    instance_eval(&block)
  end
end

A.new do
  hello
  C.new
end
```

When I run this code I get

```
hello
This is C
hello
-:25:in `block in ': uninitialized constant C (NameError)
    from -:19:in `instance_eval'
    from -:19:in `initialize'
    from -:23:in `new'
    from -:23:in `'
```

I understand that it has to do with bindings and how methods and objects are binded to class. What I cannot understand is how come I have access to `C` within `A`, but not when I eval the `block`. I would expect them to be in the same scope.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the below code

```
A.new do
  hello
  C.new
end
```

You are are trying to create the object of `C`, as if it is defined in the scope of the class `Object`. No, it is not. class `C` is defined inside the scope of module `B`. And you need to tell that explicitly as `B:C.new`.

Above explanation is for the error *-:25:in 'block in ': uninitialized constant C (NameError)*.

> What I cannot understand is how come I have access to C within A ?

[`Module#constants`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Module.html#method-i-constants) has the answer for you :-

> Returns an array of the names of the constants accessible in **mod**. This includes the names of *constants* in any included modules (example at start of section), unless the inherit parameter is set to `false`.

Look at the example :

```
module M
  X = 10
  class D; Y = 10 ;end
end
class C
  include M
  def initialize
    p self.class.constants
  end
end

C.new
# >> [:X, :D]
```

Now applying to your example :

```
module B
  class C
    def initialize
      'This is C'
    end
  end

  def hello
    'hello'
  end
end

class A
  include B

  def initialize(&block)
    p self.class.constants
    C.new  # it will work
    #instance_eval(&block)
  end
end

A.new do
  hello
  C.new # but this will throw error.
end

# it confirms that C is accessible, within the method.
# That is the same reason you got the output "This is C"
# >> [:C]
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you. That indeed makes it easier to understand what it wrong. Is there any way I can do it without having to specify the full namespace?